# getting key from keytool - cant open config file

Tags: openssl, keytool

[image]

I read a lot of wuestion here and still didnt manage to solve my problem.

keytool. exe is here : C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool.exe

debug keystore is here : C:\Users\myname.android\debug.keystore

thanks

EDIT
I read this http://www.weatherimagery.com/blog/windows-cant-open-config-file-usrlocalsslopenssl-cnf/

and it tell to set OPENSSL_CONF=c:[PATH TO YOUR OPENSSL DIRECTORY]\bin\openssl.cfg
but I only find openssl.exe and not openssl.cfg

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do here. It is not clear. The error clearly states the problem i.e. you are using keytool and it will allow only one of the command names listed. `androiddebugkey` is not a command that keytool utility understands.